# Is there a pre-existing .NET assembly or NuGet package (or similar) that has the functions, types, and constants from user32.dll?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, dllimport, .net-core

Is there any way to get WinAPI (the user32.dll part) bindings for a .net core application (like a nuget package containing the declarations for methods/enums/structs).

Or is the only way to PInvoke every WinAPI call i require manually, like the following example. It's just tedious work an I hope there is some auto generated stuff for it (and most likely I'm not the first person doing this anyway) :)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "CreateWindowExW")]
public static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(WindowStylesEx dwExStyle, string lpClassName,
    string lpWindowName, WindowStyles dwStyle, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight,
    IntPtr hWndParent, IntPtr hMenu, IntPtr hInstance, IntPtr lpParam);
```

Comment: There's [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PInvoke.Windows.Core/) and [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PInvoke.User32) (which depends on the first, I believe this second one is .NET Framework only), but I haven't tried them, so just commenting

Comment: @Jcl Seems good enough to me to post as an answer.

Comment: @Jcl basically something like I am looking for, but contains only a fraction of the WinApi and doesn't contain the bindings I require (window handling, gdi, etc).

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/ is a good resource

Comment: I have fallen in love with writing [C++/cli libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx) for my WinAPI calls, you get to use the .h header files to get all the constants and endpoints but you still get to expose .NET classes.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain As I am targeting .NET Core there is no C++/CLI for me, but otherwise this would be an option.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows API Interop library](https://winapilib.codeplex.com/) is an MIT-licensed collection of PInvokes. There isn't an assembly or NuGet package but you could export the source code from the TFS [repository](https://winapilib.svn.codeplex.com/svn).